# Translation of "After classes were over at X College, I went to Japan with my family"

Tags: traducción, pretérito

How can I translate this?

> After classes were over at X College, I went to Japan with my family.

So far I have:

> Después de las clases habían terminado en X College, fui a Japan con
>   mi familia.

Comment: _Japón_ is Spanish for "Japan" and for "college" we usually say "La universidad". "X College" could be "La Autónoma / La Politécnica / Harvard"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Después de **que** las clases en X College **terminaron**, fui a Japón con mi
>   familia.

A bit old-fashioned/literary:

> Después de que terminaron las clases en X College , fui a Japón con mi familia.

Comment: You could also say `Después de que las clases en X College terminaron, fui a Japón con mi familia.` Hubieron terminado makes it unnecessarily complicated IMHO.

Comment: @joze from a strict grammatical standpoint, the anterior preterite let's us know immediacy of the departure to Japan, whereas with simple preterite that's only implied but not guaranteed (he simply went to Japan *sometime* after classes finished, but maybe other things happened in between). Using adverbs like inmediatemente or justo can allow you to show the same relationship with simple preterite, though.

Comment: @guifa Well it depends on what the speaker wants to say. Simply using the preterite is easier for learners while having the same *perceived* meaning. While speaking spanish I personally rarely use the anterior preterite.

Comment: Shouldn't be `terminarAn` because it refers to the classes (femenin)?

Comment: @Joze Absolutely.  That's why I said from a strict one.  Not many people really use the anterior preterite anymore, I don't, at least, and I even regularly use future subjunctive even in speech :-)  For learners, it can also be beneficial to push them to the pluperfect, which is even easier to conjugate. (*justo después de que habían terminado las clases, fui a Japón*)

Comment: @fedorqui no, *terminaran* would be the imperfect subjunctive, but we need indicative in this case because when he left for Japan (main clause), the classes had in fact already finished.  Verbs don't agree on gender, though the participle does agree in the passive construction (*fue terminado/a/os/as*)

Comment: @guifa mmm but it sounds quite strange to me. Using another example _Después de que el río subiera, se desalojaron a los viandantes_ I think is the same case and we say "subiera", not "subió". Or maybe I've been saying it wrong all my life...